# mysql - order by frequency with multiple columns

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate-functions

I have a table with 5 columns:

- tag 1
- tag 2
- tag 3
- tag 4
- tag 5

If I want to show results ordered by the popularity(frequency) of those tags, what kind of query would i use?

Answer (score 4):

Because the table isn't normalized, you'll have to flatten it first:

```
SELECT a.column, a.tag1 AS tag
  FROM TABLE a
UNION ALL
SELECT b.column, b.tag2
  FROM TABLE b
UNION ALL
SELECT c.column, c.tag3
  FROM TABLE c      
UNION ALL
SELECT d.column, d.tag4
  FROM TABLE d
UNION ALL
SELECT e.column, e.tag5
  FROM TABLE e
```

...before you can count them:

```
SELECT t.tag, COUNT(*) tag_popularity
  FROM (SELECT a.column, a.tag1 AS tag
          FROM TABLE a
        UNION ALL
        SELECT b.column, b.tag2
          FROM TABLE b
        UNION ALL
        SELECT c.column, c.tag3
          FROM TABLE c      
        UNION ALL
        SELECT d.column, d.tag4
          FROM TABLE d
        UNION ALL
        SELECT e.column, e.tag5
          FROM TABLE e) x
GROUP BY x.tag
ORDER BY tag_popularity DESC
```

Comment: wow... i didn't think it would be so complicated. glad i asked!

Comment: mmm there is no TABLE a TABLE b TABLE c TABLE d TABLE e, or am i failing to understand whats going on here

Comment: @doug: Only statement starting with INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE change data

Comment: @doug: TABLE a/b/c/d/e is the same table, with a different table alias so it's clear which instance is being referenced.  It'll allow you to update the "TABLE" instances in the statement without affecting the query.

Comment: wow thanks heaps. ill keep you posted on how it goes, but i certainly think you have nailed it. I have never to use groups or unions so im keen to get this under my belt